# Replace string characters with a given character

Tags: c#, string

I have a long string which contains chars and integers.
I would like to replace the character on the x,y,z... index to a given character like: '

Example: Replace chars to ' on index: 3,9 and 14

```
input:  c9e49869a1483v4d9b4ab7d394a328d7d8a3
output: c9e'9869a'483v'd9b4ab7d394a328d7d8a3
```

I am looking for some generic solution in C#

Comment: @Steve Corrected

Comment: @Rango Yes this is a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to use a `StringBuilder`, which has a read/write indexer:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string oldText = "c9e49869a1483v4d9b4ab7d394a328d7d8a3";
        string newText = ReplaceByIndex(oldText, '\'', 3, 9, 14);
        Console.WriteLine(newText);
    }

    static string ReplaceByIndex(string text, char newValue, params int[] indexes)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(text);
        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            builder[index] = newValue;
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

You could do it via a char array instead, of course:

```
static string ReplaceByIndex(string text, char newValue, params int[] indexes)
{
    var array = text.ToCharArray();
    foreach (var index in indexes)
    {
        array[index] = newValue;
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

Comment: @Johnny: What would that validation do? Presumably, throw an exception - which will happen naturally anyway. (And the resulting exception will be entirely suitable IMO.) Sure, upfront validation would make the error case slightly faster (by avoiding copying the text) but it would also make the *success* case slower (by doing extra work). I'd rather keep the success case fast - exceptions are already going to be relatively slow, so an extra copy operation probably doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can try *Linq*:

```
string input = "c9e49869a1483v4d9b4ab7d394a328d7d8a3";

int[] positions = new[] {4, 10, 15}; 

string output = string.Concat(input.Select((c, i) => positions.Contains(i) ? '\'' : c));
```

Comment: While that will work, I would suggest it's significantly harder to understand *and* less efficient than using either a `StringBuilder` or a `char[]`.